# SQL Server 2016 format #,### not displaying 0 value

Tags: sql, format, sql-server-2016

I am calling

```
FORMAT(myNum, '#,###') AS myNum
```

Which works for 123456789 as the output is 123,456,789

Also works for negative numbers

However, 0 is showing up as a blank field.

How do I get 0 to show up as 0?  I am also curious as to why 0 is being removed as the query without the format shows 0 in that column's field when there should be a 0.

Note: I do not need any decimals and would prefer to use the above code if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display the 0, if it is zero, you should use:

```
FORMAT(myNum, '#,###0') AS myNum
```

According to this Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634206.aspx

> ### 0 (zero character)
>
> Digit placeholder. Displays a digit or a zero. If the expression has a digit in the position where the zero appears in the format string, displays the digit; otherwise, displays a zero in that position.
>
> If the number has fewer digits than there are zeros (on either side of the decimal) in the format expression, displays leading or trailing zeros. If the number has more digits to the right of the decimal separator than there are zeros to the right of the decimal separator in the format expression, rounds the number to as many decimal places as there are zeros. If the number has more digits to the left of the decimal separator than there are zeros to the left of the decimal separator in the format expression, displays the extra digits without modification.
>
> ### # Digit placeholder:
>
> Displays a digit or nothing. If the expression has a digit in the position where the # character appears in the format string, displays the digit; otherwise, displays nothing in that position.
>
> This symbol works like the 0 digit placeholder, except that leading and trailing zeros aren't displayed if the number has fewer digits than there are # characters on either side of the decimal separator in the format expression.